# GrabCut Effect on Captured Image in Android using opencv

Tags: android, opencv

I am working on an android project using opencv.I'm following some tutorial in internet ,have done "How to capture Image using Opencv,show in ImageView,Here is the Code for that ,

https://gist.github.com/manikavi/46cbdedba34d338c201f5cea6242fd2a

Output Of above code is

[image]

My Next requirement is ,Just Select & Cut affected wound part and measure size of the wound,I have done lot of research for this,but i'm not getting  how to start,Can i get help from Some one ?

Comment: `Just Select & Cut affected wound part and measure size`, Would the user select manually or you want it to be automatic ?

Comment: If possible automatically,else manually,Is is possible using openCV?

Comment: It would be hard and less accurate in automatic case, But easy in manual way, You need to create a mask image using the gesture by the user on the input image and then use that mask as alpha channel

Comment: okay then I will go with manual way,I want to do in android app.All terms are new to me like "mask,alpha",Could you please give me some example

Comment: I would recommend you to read some basic OpenCV docs.